# Is it possible to send scheduler event to SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a use case that allows users to schedule some jobs in my application. For example, a user can pick up a daily time (e.g. at 13:00) to transfer money to a selected account. Different users can pick up different time either daily, monthly or weekly.

Currently I create one scheduler cron job in `AWS Scheduler` to trigger a lambda every minute, this lambda finds all scheduled jobs based on current time, then send those jobs as individual events to a SQS. Another lambda will pull events from the SQS to do the real job.

My problem is that the `scheduler lambda` has to run every minute which most of the time it will get empty result. Is it possible to send a scheduled event to SQS which let SQS to make the even based on scheduled time? I did some search but I couldn't find any solution around SQS. If not, what could be a good solution in AWS service to achieve that?

I have looked at cloudwatch event, EventBridge and AWS scheduler. but none of them support user based schedule. If I have millions of users, I need a way to be able to let each of the user to schedule their own task.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to use AWS StepFunctions with a Task Timer. StepFunction allows the use of a Wait state that will wait until a specified date and time.

Have a look at this example (which is using SNS, but this can easily be modified to trigger different targets): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html

Comment: The task timer accepts a delay timestamp to run, but it doesn't support a scheduler. What I need is to provide function that can be run on, for example, daily basis.

Comment: another case is that if there are one million users submit their schedule job, is it good to use step function to manage those 1 million requests?